# dependency management for JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs

I am currently using bower for dependency management that downloads all my project dependencies with one command. Now I also started using Gruntjs. Now the problem is when I want to download e.g. jQuery dependency using bower, it downloads several several other js files too in libs folder. Then I use grunt to minify all of my written JavaScript with jQuery library that is inside libs folder. Now the problem is that it also minifies and concatinate those unnecessary files inside jquery folder which are loaded using bower.

My question is that is there a way so that bower downloads only jquery.js file or is there a way for grunt to concatenate only jquery.js files with the rest of my code?

If yes then how?

**UPDATE**

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({

            jshint: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
                },
                target: {
                    src: 'src/js/**/*.js'
                }
            },

            csslint: {
                options: {
                    csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
                },
                target: {
                    src: 'src/css/**/*.css'
                }
            },

            copy: {
                dist: {
                    cwd: 'src/', expand: true, src: '**', dest: 'dist/'
                }
            },

            concat: {
                options: {
                    // separator: ';'
                },
                target: {
                    src: ['dist/js/jquery.js', 'dist/js/**/*.js'], // make sure jquery is loaded first
                    dest: 'dist/js/compiled.js'
                }
            },

            uglify: {
                options: {
                    mangle: true,
                    compress: true,
                    banner: '/* Test banner */\n'
                },
                target: {
                    src: 'dist/js/compiled.js',
                    dest: 'dist/scripts/compiled.min.js'
                }
            },

            uncss: {
                dist: {
                    files: [
                        { src: 'src/*.html', dest: 'dist/css/compiled.min.css' }
                    ]
                }
            },

            cssmin: {
                options: {
                    // banner: '/* My minified css file */'
                },
                target: {
                    src: 'dist/css/*.css',
                    dest: 'dist/styles/compiled.min.css'
                }
            },

            // Deletes all .js files, but skips min.js files
            clean: ['dist/js/', 'dist/css/'],

            processhtml: {
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'dist/index.html': ['src/index.html']
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');

        grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uncss', 'csslint', 'copy', 'concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'clean', 'processhtml']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell Grunt to only use just the one JQuery file as a target for concatenation, and then only that value will be picked up.

I'm assuming you have a glob in the format of 'bower_components/**/*.js', instead of doing that specific glob you should simply make a glob that includes just jquery.  Remember the src files can also be an array, not just a string.
You should be able to do ['bower_components/jquery/jquery.js', 'bower_components/path/to/other/lib.js'].

Comment: Could you elaborate `instead of doing that specific glob you should simply make a glob that includes just jquery` how can I do this. any example?

Comment: I would need a few more details, mainly what does your grunt file look like, before I could say more.

Comment: Could you please help me out.